# Flux from WebClient behaves differently than Flux from File.readLines

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two different sources of some IDs I have to do work with.  One is from a file, another is from URL.  When I'm creating `Flux` from the Files' lines, I can perfectly well work on it.  When I'm switching the Flux-creating function with the one that uses WebClient....get(), I get different results; the WebClient does never get called for some reason.

```
private Flux<String> retrieveIdListFromFile(String filename) {
  try {
    return Flux.fromIterable(Files.readAllLines(ResourceUtils.getFile(filename).toPath()));
  } catch (IOException e) {
    return Flux.error(e);
  }
}
```

Here the WebClient part...

```
private Flux<String> retrieveIdList() {
  return client.get()
      .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("capdocuments_201811v2/selectRaw")
          .queryParam("q", "-P_Id:[* TO *]")
          .queryParam("fq", "DateLastModified:[2010-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2016-12-31T00:00:00Z]")
          .queryParam("fl", "id")
          .queryParam("rows", "10")
          .queryParam("wt", "csv")
          .build())
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToFlux(String.class);
}
```

When I do a `subscribe(System.out::println)`on the WebClient's flux, nothing happens.  When I do a blockLast(), it works (URL is called, data returned).  I don't get why, and how to correct this, and what I'm doing wrong.
With the flux that originates from the file, even the subscribe works fine.  I sort of thought, that Fluxes are interchangable...

When I do a `retrieveIdList().log().subscribe()`:

```
INFO [main] reactor.Flux.OnAssembly.1 | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxOnAssembly.OnAssemblySubscriber)
INFO [main] reactor.Flux.OnAssembly.1 | request(unbounded)
```

When I do the same with blockLast() instead of subscribe():

```
INFO [main] reactor.Flux.OnAssembly.1 | onSubscribe([Fuseable] FluxOnAssembly.OnAssemblySubscriber)
INFO [main] reactor.Flux.OnAssembly.1 | request(unbounded)
INFO [reactor-http-nio-4] reactor.Flux.OnAssembly.1 | onNext(id)
.
.
.
```

Comment: Could you add a `log()` operator on the webclient to see what's going on? Also, could enable `wiretap` on the underlying reactor netty HttpClient so that we can see the HTTP request/response?

Comment: could you update your question with the requested information? you're also missing the HTTP logs.

Comment: There is nothing, no request is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your question update, it seems that nothing is waiting on the processing to finish. I assume this is a batch or CLI application, and not a web application?

Assuming the following:

```
Flux<User> users = userService.fetchAll();
```

Calling `blockLast` on a `Flux` will trigger the processing and `block` until the result is there.

Calling `subscribe` on it will trigger the processing asynchronously; we're seeing the subscriber `request` elements in your logs, but nothing more. This probably means that the JVM exits before any elements are published - nothing is waiting on the result.

If you're effectively writing some CLI/batch application and not processing requests within a web application, you can `block` on the final reactive pipeline to get the result. If you wish to write that result to a file or send it to a different service, then you should compose on it with reactor operators.

Comment: Aha, that could well be... I'm indeed using this as a batch-process, sorry I didn't mention that!  
My problem now then is: How do I parallelize it? There is no block function on a ParallelFlux, right?  Do you have any pointers from the top of your head? I'm sure this has been done before ;-)

Comment: what do you mean by parallelize? everything is done asynchronously and in a non-blocking manner until the point where you gather the results.

Comment: Using parallel() and runOn() won't allow you to blockLast(), so I now understand I misphrased my question...  here the solution to blocking - 
.retrieveIdList()
        .parallel(10)
        .log()
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .sequential() // <--- this here will make blockLast possible again
        .blockLast()

Comment: This is a totally different question and I don't understand it. Could you raise a different question and provide some background on what you're trying to achieve, show a code snippet of how you're trying to do it, what's the expected result and what's the result you're getting instead?